# Testing if your web browser does support SPDY

Tags: browser, spdy

Is there site which would test, if your browser supports SPDY, and is configured for optimum performance?

If not, maybe we should create one?

Comment: try https://spdycheck.org/

Answer (score 2):

There was a site called http://spdytest.com/ but it's currently down due to maintenance.

Supported Browser are currently listet on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY#Browser_support_and_usage)

Alternatively you can visit https://www.modspdy.com/ and look at your debugging tool at how the files are beeing loaded. I would post example images for both cases but i don't have enough reputation points :-)

Comment: The links to spdytest.com and modspdy.com are not longer valid.
The first is now an ad page, the second is now offline.

Answer (score 2):

SPDY indicator is a [Chrome Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spdy-indicator/mpbpobfflnpcgagjijhmgnchggcjblin) that shows a green thunder icon for sites where SPDY is enabled. Alternatively you can also go to chrome://net-internals/#spdy live SPDY sessions.

It is not possible for a site or plugin to tell whether site is optimized for SPDY because there are so many factors that decides a site's performance (page load time). Here are a few important factors that can be crucial for a site's adaptability towards SPDY

1. Distribution of traffic between SPDY and non SPDY enabled browser - There are some techniques like domain sharding that was useful to improve performance with HTTP 1.0 but can hurt a site's performance with SPDY. Since server decides how many shards to use for a domain without the knowledge whether the client supports SPDY it becomes tricky to pick the correct number of mirrors.
2. SPDY supports server push which means the servers now should intelligently decide which resources to push. A site inspector or browser plugin has hardly any knowledge about the interdependency or the relevancy between resources. So it is really difficult to suggest a combination that is optimal.

In short a site's performance depends on several factors and there are a zillion combinations for those factors to try out. To suggest an optimized combination for a site the tool / plugin should be capable of evaluating those zillion combinations.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using this site ( https://spdy.centminmod.com/flags.html ) which is a SPDY demo site displaying hundreds of country flags on the same page.

It provides comparison videos to see how it would load for SPDY and non-SPDY enabled browsers.